# How do I set Thunderbird to notify me of new emails in only certain folders?

Tags: gmail, thunderbird, notifications

I use Gmail with Thunderbird, which is working great, except for the part where I get a new email. It shows me the new email twice when notifying because it appears in both the inbox and All Mail folders. I know I can just unsubscribe to the All Mail folder, but then I can't back it up like many people do with Thunderbird. How do I set Thunderbird to notify me of new emails in only certain folders?

Comment: Having the same issue here, except that I don't even know how to "unsubscribe to the All Mail folder" since I don't need to back it up. Any hints on that?

Comment: I just unsubscribe from "All Mail", as you've suggested.  I'm sure you realize there are many ways to back up your Gmail, but here is a nice list of options: http://www.mattcutts.com/blog/backup-gmail-in-linux-with-getmail/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Right click on the folder you don't want notifications for;
2. Select "Properties";
3. Uncheck the checkbox "When getting new messages for this account, always check this folder".

Comment: It's unchecked but I'm still always notified about it...

Comment: Same here, v68.7.0

Answer (score 8):

2021: Answer now seems to be the [Mailbox Alert extension](https://addons.thunderbird.net/en-US/thunderbird/addon/mailbox-alert/), which allows setting of alerts down to folder level and works in current Thunderbird version as of this message 78.6

Comment: I wanted not only notifications from specific folders (because I could miss them), but also a tray icon to persist with the unread messages status (but only for specific folders, not all folders). That is why I was searching this question. Is there a solution with tray icon persistant notification?

I also wanted to use Kmail instead of thunderbird. I went to menu Settings -> Kmail settings -> Modules -> Akonadi agents -> New mail notifications -> settings button. In new opened window went to Folders tab and unchecked all folders except those I was interested in to receive notifications for.

Comment: As it is with Thunderbird add-ons, they die. This one is not available for v115 anymore and the author's website doesn't make the impression that it's still maintained. Used it with Tb 60 for a long time, but looking for an upgrade now.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe it is possible with filters and the [FiltaQuilla Add-on](http://mesquilla.com/extensions/filtaquilla/)? The add-on adds many new filter actions and one of them is to disable notifications. You could try to add a new filter rule without conditions, action “Do not notify” and then apply it to the All Mail folder. (I haven’t tried it myself.)

Comment: This was the correct answer for Thunderbird up until recently. With version 78 Thunderbird has now rendered many old addons useless, including FiltaQuilla. And there still doesn't seem to be a native way to do this.
By the way, this is the github repository: https://github.com/RealRaven2000/FiltaQuilla

Comment: 2023: FiltaQuilla seems to be working again for current versions (I'm using 102 and it's working fine).

Answer (score 1):

Not sure where it is, but within Tb, write a message rule that notifies receipant of new mail received then filter within the rule you're creating to flag only the folder you want notification for.