# How to make KMail to show notifications of new emails only from specific folders?

Tags: email, kde, notifications, kmail

In my mailbox there are lots of folders. I want to receive a notifications of new letters on a certain folders, but stop nofifications from other folders.

There is a similar [question](https://superuser.com/q/144170/873855) for Thunderbird. I am using KDE and prefer to use environment native application called KMail instead of Thunderbird.

Also I would like the notification to be persistent because I can miss it. Is it possible to keep a notification displayed and require a manual action? Or at least a system tray icon with new letters indicator?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible.

First, you need to enable tray icon. Go to Settings -> Configure KMail. Go to Appearance category, choose General tab, in the System Tray block enable checkbox "Enable system tray icon" and "Show unread email in Taskbar".

Now you need to specify folders you are interested in. In Configure Kmail window switch to Accounts category, choose Receiving tab, in the New Mail Notification block click Other Actions button. Then a new window will open. This window could also be opened if you select Plugins category -> Akonadi Agents -> Notifications about new mail settings button. At a Display tab enable checkbox "Show Action Buttons" and "Keep Persistent Notification". Click Apply. Then choose Folders tab, deselect all folders except those which you want to receive notifications for. Click Apply.

Now Kmail will keep a notification shown until you manually make some action (mark as read, remove letter, show letter or just close notification). Also, a KMail tray icon will be shown with a dot, indicating there is unread new folder in your interested folders.

P.S. While testing, I have noticed a strange thing. It only worked for the *new* letters. Just marking a letter as unread in web interface was not detected as unread by kmail for some reason, so there is no notification. Probably, I have to configure it somewhere else.