# How to show action buttons (reply/mark read/delete) in KMail notifications?

Tags: email, kde, notifications, kmail

The KMail shows a notification when receiving new letter, but is it possible to add Action Buttons to the notification? Such as open, mark as spam, mark as read, delete and so on.
The setting in kmail are not such intuitive, and I cannot find where is that option.

Answer (score 0):

Enable the actions for email.

Go to menu `Settings` -> `Configure KMail`. Go to `Plugins` category. Under `Akonadi Agents` choose `Notifications about new mail` settings button. A new window will open. At a `Display` tab enable checkbox `Show Action Buttons`, then click `Apply`. [image]

If you wish to receive notifications only from specific folders, see   [How to make KMail to show notifications of new emails only from specific folders?](https://superuser.com/questions/1624930/how-to-make-kmail-to-show-notifications-of-new-emails-only-from-specific-folders).